# Filtering results by user name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have this code:

```
// GET: Teachers/Edit/5
public ActionResult Edit(Guid? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    string uname = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    Teachers teachers = db.teachers.Find(id);
    if (teachers == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    ViewBag.GroupID = new SelectList(db.groups, "GroupID", "GroupName", teachers.GroupID);
    return View(teachers);
}
```

I am attempting to filter my returned results by `id` (which is my DB key) but also by the `user name` which is also stored into the database but not as a key.

I'm not sure of the syntax, but I am pretty sure find is not the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SingleOrDefault`:

```
db.teachers.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == id && x.UserName == username);
```

It returns a single, specific element of a sequence, or a default value if that element is not found. It will throw exception if there is more than one element in the result.

***Additionally***, you can also use `Single()`, `First()`, `FirstOrDefault()` in such places. Here is the differences between them:

- `First()` - throws exception if empty or not found, does not throw if duplicate
- `FirstOrDefault()` - returns default if empty or not found, does not throw if duplicate
- `Single()` - throws exception if empty or not found, throws if duplicate exists
- `SingleOrDefault()` - returns default if empty or not found, throws if duplicate exists

  ---

***P.S:*** You haven't stated your column names. So, I have just guessed their names. You can change them as you wish.